# Angular 4/5 ngFor unexpected index error

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, iteration

I am trying to make a list of inputs and I can't get ngFor to compile.

```
<div *ngFor="let q of questions; let i = index" class="col-3">
  <div class="group">
    <input [(ngModel)]="q" [class.ng-not-empty]="q.length > 0">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Question {{i}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

my definitions are set as such:

```
questions: string[];
constructor() {
  this.questions = ['blah', 'blah', 'blah'];
}
```

the error i get is:

```
ERROR in : Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!
```

If I remove the index definition it works and i have tried all of the following:

```
*ngfor="let q of questions | index as i"
*ngfor="let q of questions; index as i"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `[(ngModel)]="q"` because you are trying to assign to a local variable in your HTML (in this case, `let q`)

Try this:

```
[(ngModel)]="questions[i]";
```

Comment: okay i get it now, so i cant access q outside of the div tag i define it in? not even children?

Comment: When you loop with *ngFor, you are explicitly creating a local template variable `let q of questions` with `let q` being the creation. So now you are trying to assign NgModel a value that exists only in the template(the html), but not in your component. NgModel cannot assign to local variables.

Comment: will it let me do that if i use the ng-template option?

Comment: seems like a waste of storage to assign it and never use it, i'd like to avoid that